# Text within Checkbox is not updated with localized String

Tags: android, checkbox, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-checkbox

I'm seeing a strange bug with my android application, where I've a checkbox which is associated with a dialog (ie' which shows up in UI as part of dialog).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox1"            
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/textcontent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkbox_text_size"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="end"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the language is set as Japanese ie' when the locale is set to JP - the jp resource corresponding to the string is not shown in UI.

Note: Tried debugging this issue with UIAutomatorViewer - I could see the japanese value for the string `textcontent` is replaced within the layout - but the value seen on the screen is `english`. I'm not sure why this discrepancy is observed.

Comment: To someone who has raised a flag to close this question, please let me know how it violates the community guidence. Raising the flag without leaving appropriate comment doesn't seem to make any sense at all !!!!

Comment: Yeah closing flag was harsh. Have you tested it on Some other device it might be device specific (it goes haywire sometimes i have faced few issues in past)? Also Are you setting `CheckBox` text dynamically or just in xml ?

Comment: Haven't tried it on other devices. I've tried on pie (physical device). I'll set up emulator and try it on other devices. I'm not setting the text dynamically. It's just the xml which I'm expecting it to get updated based on the current locale value. Please correct me if i'm missing something..

Comment: Also add code for Locale change in the question .

Comment: No actually the locale is not changed dynamically - even after restart the issue is persisting. ie' this issue is happening if i change the locale to value other than english. And locale change I mean by changing the keyboard language.

Comment: This is weird . r u sure you have the entry for `textcontent` in other `string.xml`? double check it .

Comment: yeah 100% sure i've checked this multiple times. I've checked even by decompiling the apk - it has the resources.

Comment: Did you tried recreating the activity?

Comment: @Eyosiyas: Yes I've tried recreating the activity - but it didn't help. The only thing which I could find so far is some third party keyboard is messing up. Once I disabled it, I'm not observing this issue. Yet to figure out the root cause but this is what I've so far..